# Configuring puppet with passenger causing port conflict with apache2

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet, so this might a simple issue that I am stuck with.
While installing puppet I needed to use Proxy Certificate Traffic so that the agents can reach the CA master.
I have Ubuntu `14.04 64 bit` for server configuration.

Now, based on the documentations at I have started working on it.

- https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scaling_multiple_masters.html#option-2-proxy-certificate-traffic
- https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/passenger.html

After I install the puppet server [puppet enterprise version 3.3.2-ubuntu-14.0amd64], and making sure

```
puppet agent --verbose --no-daemonize --onetime
```

is run,  I run the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 ruby1.8-dev rubygems-integration
```

Once the installation is done I run,

```
$ sudo a2enmod ssl
```

It says that it is enabling the module `ssl` and asks to re-start apapche2.

But when I try to restart apache2 it fails saying

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
```

Now I find the reason is pe-httpd is already running on this port

```
$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':443'

tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      32622/pe-httpd 

$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':8140'**

tcp6       0      0 :::8140                 :::*                    LISTEN      32622/pe-httpd
```

I understand `WEBrick` is probably already running and that is why this conflict is arising.

Now my question is do I need to stop pe-http here.

In documentation towards the end it is mentioned:

> Ensure that any WEBrick puppet master process is stopped before starting the Apache service

but not very clear when this action to be carried out, can I stop it when I am running enabling ssl and headers modules?

Comment: I think I got the issue resolved. After following the instructions as it is one needs to stop pe-httpd at the end before restarting apache2. That should work fine.

Comment: Note that this type of question is OT for StackOverflow, since it deals with operations. It would be more suitable on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks @Felix Frank for the input.